# Issue with SVG path not animating

Tags: html, css, next.js, css-animations

I have an SVG I'm trying to animate, but it is not working for some reason.

[image: japan map]

This is my component where I'm loading the svg

```js
import { JapanMap } from "../illustrations/japanMap";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <JapanMap />
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is the svg itself and the css:

```css
#japanMap {
  stroke-dasharray: 31818.841796875;
  stroke-dashoffset: 31818.841796875;
  animation: draw 6s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dash-offset: 0;
  }
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

export const JapanMap = () => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1"
      id="2338971"
      viewBox="0 0 2270.4019 2838.8689"
      height="801.19189"
      width="640.75787"
    >
      <g transform="translate(563.71426,965.56689)" id="2398">
        <path
          id="japanMap"
          stroke="#000000"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="m 1705.6746,-614.68501 c -1.7675,4.9831 -4.7911,8.4043 -7.4279,8.4043 -1.3295,0 -1.961,0.6807 -1.961,2.1138 0,6.3193 -8.9706,15.0674 -14.5534,14.1926 -1.6206,-0.2539 -3.8466,-0.5178 etc..."
        ></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

What could be the reason that it's not animating? I'm not too familiar with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Might just be the typo in your animation.
there's should be no `-` between `dash` and `offset`.

`stroke-dash-offset: 0;` becomes:

```
@keyframes draw {
  to {       
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

## Example

```css
svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: draw 3s ease alternate infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```